# How do I blackout a video for various time periods

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to say black out the video, keep audio, from minute 1 to 1:30 and 5 to 5:45 how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawbox=c=black:t=fill:enable='between(t,60,90)+between(t,300,345)' -c:a copy out.mp4
```

If you have an older version of ffmpeg, you will have to use `max` in place of `fill`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, getting a `Missing ')' or too many args in 'between(t'`

Comment: Escape the commas.

Comment: I had the same issue as André. Shouldn't the answer be updated to escape commas?